# Presto / Athena: How can I group by one column's categorical values while doing time-series window functions on another column?

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto, amazon-athena, anomaly-detection

I have an Athena table with the following fields:

- `date` (`str` that I'm `date_parse()`ing to `date` format)
- `entity` (`str`, categorical variable)
- `value` (`float`, the target metric for my analysis)

Each `entity` has one `value` per `date`.

I'm analyzing variance -- specifically, identifying the `entity`s for which something unusual is happening in the `value` field. Previously, I was pulling out a single `entity`'s data and doing some simple anomaly detection in Pandas using the [ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) functions.

I'm working with a lot of data, though, and it updates daily. So I would prefer not to run the entire `ewm` time-series analysis on the thousands of `entity`s in this table every day. My workaround is to try to calculate a `z-score` using a window function in Athena, then run the more expensive analysis on the top z-scores for any given day. But I can't seem to figure out how to write the query such that the `z-score` is only calculated with respect to each `entity` and the relevant `day`.

Here's my stab at the initial query, which works for a single `entity`:

```
with subquery AS 
    (SELECT date_parse(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS day, 
     value, 
     entity
    FROM mytable
    WHERE date_parse(date, '%Y-%m-%d') > date_parse('201-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
    AND entity = 'sample_entity'), 

data_with_stddev AS 
    (SELECT day,
         value,
         entity,
         (value - avg(value)
        OVER ()) / (stddev(value)
        OVER ()) AS zscore
    FROM subquery
    ORDER BY  1)

SELECT *
FROM data_with_stddev
WHERE day > date_parse('2019-12-25', '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY  zscore desc
```

The way I've done this in the past is to run a bash script that iterates over all of the `entity` variables and executes a separate query for each. I'd like to avoid that. Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  How many rows  per entity per day?

Comment: Thanks -- I just figured it out. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a `partition by` clause, like this:

```
...
OVER (PARTITION BY entity ORDER BY day asc)) / (stddev(value)
OVER (PARTITION BY entity ORDER BY day asc)) AS zscore
...
```

Docs: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html

Answer (score 0):

```
with sales_stats as
    (select avg(sales) as mean,
            stddev(sales) as sd
    from zscore),
    visitor_stats as
    (select avg(visitors) as mean,
            stddev(visitors) as sd
    from zscore)
select dt,
    abs(sales - sales_stats.mean) / sales_stats.sd as z_score_sales,
    abs(visitors - visitor_stats.mean) / visitor_stats.sd as z_score_visitors
from sales_stats,
    visitor_stats,
    zscore;
```